# how does the count function in mysql work?

Tags: mysql, count

First and foremost, this is part of an assignment, but I'm trying to get more clarification on how the count() function works when querying a db.

The question is: List the name, SSN and the number of courses the student has taken (courses with the same CourseNumber taken in different quarters are counted as different courses).

I've been querying using this:

```
SELECT S.Name, S.SSN, COUNT(*)
FROM Student S, Enrollment E
WHERE S.SSN = E.SSN
GROUP BY S.SSN
```

which seems to return the correct answer, but I'm not sure why.  As a result, I can't seem to get the next questions (assuming courses with the same CourseNumber taken in different quarters are considered as one course) correct.

Here are the create table commands so you can see which table holds what info:

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
SSN INT(9),
Name VARCHAR(20),
Major VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (SSN)
);

CREATE TABLE Course(
CourseNumber INT(5),
PrerequisiteCourseNumber INT(10),
CourseTitle VARCHAR(10),
NumberUnits INT(2),
PRIMARY KEY (CourseNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Section(
CourseNumber INT(5),
Quarter VARCHAR(10),
RoomNumber INT(5),
DayTime VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (CourseNumber,Quarter),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber) REFERENCES Course(CourseNumber)
);


CREATE TABLE Enrollment(
SSN INT(9),
CourseNumber INT(5),
Quarter VARCHAR(10),
Grade VARCHAR(1),
PRIMARY KEY (SSN,CourseNumber,Quarter),
FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES Student(SSN),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber) REFERENCES Course(CourseNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (Quarter) REFERENCES Section(Quarter)
);
```

Any pointers?

Comment: maybe here is some information about count and group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039194/how-does-the-groupby-and-count-work-in-sql

Comment: *this is part of an assignment* Nothing to do with your question, but if SSN stands for social security number ... you would never store raw SSN's in a database table in real life ;-)

Comment: @Leigh of course.  Just a school assignment so no real SSNs are stored and the db is local. :)

Comment: @codenko - Yeah, it sounded like a school assignment, but .. nice to hear someone with common sense :-) You would be amazed how many people actually *would* store information like that in clear text ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are doing is using old join syntax (pre ansi syntax) where you do a cross join of tables and use the where to turn it into a join. an equivalent query would be this.

```
SELECT S.Name, S.SSN, COUNT(*)
FROM Student S
JOIN Enrollment E ON S.SSN = E.SSN
GROUP BY S.SSN
```

Now to answer your question about what the count is doing and stuff..

COUNT() returns a count of every row that is returned.
GROUP BY groups all of the records by a common ground aka your SSN field. so if a student has 5 SSN rows in the table then his count will be 5.

Now for the part you are looking for with course numbers.. you need to JOIN those tables on appropriate fields and add a field to your group by for each quarter

aka add to the previous code..

```
WHERE E.quarter = whatever_quarter_you_want
```

you can add more to this query if you need to. but add data to your question if you want a more full answer.

Comment: Thank you!  This makes a lot more sense now!  Still having issues with the second question however.  I'm using 
`SELECT S.Name, S.SSN, COUNT(E.CourseNumber)  
FROM Student S  
INNER JOIN Enrollment E  
ON S.SSN = E.SSN  
GROUP BY S.SSN  
  
` which gives me every name, ssn and a counted number of courses for that specific ssn given that an enrollment row exists for that ssn.  

The second question asks for a list of SSNs and Names with a count for  courses that don't have the same course number.  Should I be using a subquery for this?

Comment: @codenko you can try changing your inner join to a left join if you want to include enrollments for all ssn even if it doesn't exist.. for the next part you can join the same table again but this time specify that the course number is not the same aka `LEFT JOIN enrollment e1 ON e1.SSN = s.SSN AND e1.CourseNumber <> E.CourseNumber` and then count that like so `COUNT(e1.CourseNumber <> NULL)`

Comment: Checked out the answer key and it gives this for the second problem.   `SELECT S.SSN, S.Name, Count(*) AS DistinctCourseTaken    FROM Student AS S, (SELECT DISTINCT SSN, CourseNumber FROM Enrollment ) AS E    WHERE S.SSN = E.SSN    GROUP BY S.SSN`    I'm not sure what the Distinct keyword does in this case or even means.  The Subquery is also confusing to me.

Comment: again that is doing a cross join which isn't a good idea. use the appropriate syntax.. and maybe check how old your book is that you are learning this from. thats an old practice. distinct is exactly what it sounds like. distinct records... so if there is a duplicate from everything that is being selected then it wont select it

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is:-

```
SELECT S.Name, S.SSN, COUNT(*)
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Enrollment E
ON S.SSN = E.SSN
GROUP BY S.SSN
```

What this is doing is joining student to enrollment, so giving multiple rows for each student, one for each course / quarter they are enrolled on. It is then grouped by SSN (student number?) to count up the number of course / quarters they are enrolled on. You should really group by S.Name as well (while MySQL won't object, most flavours of SQL would).

Note that COUNT(*) counts the number of rows. You could use COUNT(E.CourseNumber) which would count the number of rows where course number is not null. Not really useful here, but can be useful with LEFT OUTER JOINs. You can also use COUNT(DISTINCT CourseNumber) to count the number of unique non null course numbers for the student.

A LEFT OUTER JOIN might also be better as this would enable you to return 0 as the counts for students who exist but who are not enrolled in any courses:-

```
SELECT S.Name, S.SSN, COUNT(DISTINCT E.CourseNumber)
FROM Student S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Enrollment E
ON S.SSN = E.SSN
GROUP BY S.Name, S.SSN
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT S.Name, S.SSN, COUNT(*)
FROM Student S, Enrollment E, Section Sec, Course C
WHERE S.SSN = E.SSN AND E.CourseNumber = Sec.CourseNumber 
AND Sec.CourseNumber = C.CourseNumber AND Sec.Quarter like E.Quarter
GROUP BY S.Name, S.SSN
```

Comment: you really think, drop out some query should answer this question?, please provide some information or explanation, what you did and why.

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why this code works, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.